# Different indexes on different replica set members

Tags: mongodb

As part of our mongo cluster, we have a hidden node that the analytics people use for reporting. Their queries are quite a bit different than the ones that our main application is optimized for.

We can improve the performance of their queries quite dramatically by adding certain indexes, which are relatively expensive to compute, and take a fair amount of memory. Those indexes should not be used by any of the queries running on our primary and secondary members, so it seems a bit silly to spend time and memory on the main replica set members to compute and keep the reporting indexes in memory.

Is there a way to create an index so that it only exists on a single replica set member? Is there a way to tell my primary and secondary nodes to not compute or store the indexes I know they will not use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes - you can use a variation on the strategy used for creating a new index in a replica set without down time.  This will require that the hidden member be taken off-line while the index(es) are created.

Here is the link for the strategy: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#procedure

In your case you will take the hidden member off-line and restart in a standalone mode (remove the --replSet option and use a different port number).  Once the member is isolated you can adjust the indexes (remove un-needed ones and add new ones).  Once the indexes are done being created restart the member with the old port and --replSet option.

The hidden member will resync to the replica set and you are all set.

Comment: Interesting. My problem is that I absolutely do not want to propagate the indexes back to the primary servers. They will degrade write performance too dramatically.

Comment: They won't.  Indexes only get propagated from the primary to the secondaries when they are created.  Since this is a hidden member it will never be the primary and the indexes will never be propagated. You have to remove the member from the replica set otherwise it is read-only and will refuse the index creation.  Once it is created the member will happily maintain it.

Comment: The indexes won't be propagated to Primary or any other secondary. The changes are only pulled from the oplog of primary, by other servers.

Comment: technically that's not true - secondaries are certainly allowed to sync off of other secondaries.  However, they will not (normally) sync off of a hidden secondary, so since this node is hidden you should be fine.

Comment: Those interested in this type of functionality may wish to comment and/or vote for this feature request: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3664

Comment: The index wouldn't propagate to other servers even if you later promoted your "hidden" server as the primary. The reason is that if you take your secondary out of the replica set (start without --replSet option), nothing will be written into the oplog while mongod runs in a standalone mode. As a result, there will never be a mention of creating such index in the oplog ever, and since the servers only sync through reading the oplog, the index wouldn't propagate.

Comment: There is actually only one scenario that comes to my mind that could expand the index to other servers, and that is if you're doing [backups](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups) from your "hidden" server and then start a new server from the backup, it would have the same indexes as the original.