# Mongodb Index On replica set members only for reporting

Tags: mongodb, indexing, replicaset

I have Mongodb setup as 1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 abiter. Is it possible to index the collections on secondary only for reporting purpose?

Comment: What do you mean? Indexes on collections are solely for the purpose of reading, i.e. reporting

Comment: Yes, I want to index on secondary collections and not on primary collections. Writing on primary collections will not have overhead of  index management.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a comment about this same topic on a separate thread, and I referenced some approaches that people claim to successfully be following to accomplish this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097239/1680471