# Is there a way to relate a score to a particular field(s) in full text index

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have a full text index based on  multiple fields and currently all have a default weight of 1. 
Now I want to search on a particular field from full text index. So I was thinking to give different weights to different fields and somehow map the score to the field(s) so that I can filter based on score and thus essentially filter on specific field(s) out of multiple fileds. But looking at how the score calculation is done (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/fts_spec.cpp) it looks like it's not that straightforward to get the mapping of score and field(s) correctly or may be not possible.

```
db.collection.createIndex({
        Name: "text",
        Line: "text",
        City: "text",
        State: "text",
        Zip: "text",

    },   {
     weights: {
       Name: 16,
       Line:8,
       City: 4,
       State: 2,
       Zip: 1,
     },
     name: "TextIndex"
   })
```

Has anybody done similar things in the past who can provide some pointers?

Comment: The weights will affect all searches. If you need all of the fields in the index, and want to limit the search to particular fields in specific queries, it may be better to use aggregation using text search + regex.

Comment: @AlexBlex I already have a regex but it is slow. So wanted to optimize . Not sure 
what you mean by weights will affect all searches. Since each filed weight is different, each field match will contribute differently to the score, right? So I am looking at a solution as to which fields have contributed to the score.

Comment: It is something different to *Now I want to search on a particular field from full text index.* I get it as you need to limit the search e.g. to `Name` and `Line`, so that if a matching word is in `City` field only, the document should not be returned. Does it accurately describe the requirement? If so, weights won't help. They affect significance of the field, i.e. order of documents wish you sort by relevance.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes you got it correct: my requirement. I am fairly sure I can make it work if I have to search on a single field(Name) only. But I was looking for a possibility if I can get a generic solution somehow.

Comment: I wonder how? Did you forget to mention something in the question that make it possible? In general case score is somewhere between 0 and weight. Your approach would work if the score was somewhere between weight and 2*weight, but it is not the case. Having 0 base you can always have weight < 1 for a word found in a very long `Name`, even though the field has weight 16. The field names suggest you may have some practical limitations on field's content, which may allow you to find weights to maximise chances of getting expected result, but you need to mention such in the question explicitly.

Comment: This is what I had in mind. If I assign a weight of 100 to Name and 1 to other fields and then if the score is greater than 5 . And given Name is not a string of unbounded length. I think it should do. I was looking at some generic solution if it exists so didn't think mentioning this would be that much relevant. Anyway I have been playing with mongo just recently. So I may not  have the clear picture of how thing works.

Comment: Yeah, it will work. You will need to do some research of your data and search strings to estimate proper weights. Since it relies on both data and query it won't be 100% reliable, yet might be acceptable. See my answer for other options you have.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb has limited support of fulltext search. Most important restrictions are documented at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#restrictions.

Since you have limited length of the strings, you can estimate the minimal score and play with weights and filter by score ranges, e.g.:

```
db.collection.createIndex({
    Name: "text",
    Line: "text",
    City: "text",
    State: "text",
    Zip: "text",

},   {
 weights: {
   Name: 10000,
   Line:1000,
   City: 100,
   State: 10,
   Zip: 1,
 },
 name: "TextIndex"
})
```

and to serach in `Line` and `State` only:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {$text:{$search: serach_string}}}, 
    {$addFields: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
    {$match: {$or:[
      // 1.01 - is the minimal score for State, higher than weight of Zip
      {score:{$gte: 1.01, $lte: 10}}, 
      // 100.01 - is the minimal score for Line, higher than total weight of Zip, State, and City
      // 1010 - is the summary weight of State and Line
      {score:{$gte: 100.01, $lte: 1010}}
    ]}}
])
```

---

For strings of arbitrary length the best you can have is combination of text search and regex:

```
db.collection.find({$and:[
    {$text:{$search: serach_string}}, 
    {$or:[{State:/regex/i}, {Line:/regex/i}]}
]})
```

You will need to tokenise the `serach_string` and get stems to build the regex. In general case it will not give you the same result as text search on index built for 2 fields only since regexps knows nothing about collations.

---

Finally, you can have multiple text indexes on hidden secondaries. It will give you the best results, but will require additional members in the replica set. See e.g.  [Different indexes on different replica set members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472392/different-indexes-on-different-replica-set-members) for details.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can put the formula for calculating the minimal score for a field with a given weight.Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there is one. It really depends on strings in the documents, and the query - both changes over time. Did I mention you need to research both, and that it is not 100% reliable? In general case one can always craft a search_string long enough to get extremely low score which will go below range boundaries.

Comment: You had this in the comment  // 2 - is the minimal score for State, higher than weight of Zip. So wanted to know how  you got that number

Comment: It's just an example, hence the comment. You have to find suitable numbers. `2` is just an indication that it must be greater than weight of `Zip`. I have changed it to `1.01` to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: OK. I was really hoping to get some hard nos that have worked for someone :)

Comment: Unfortunately text index is quite limited in mongodb. We ended up using ES in parallel exactly because of complex queries we have to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166952/discussion-between-sameer-and-alex-blex).